# multi items setup in PayPal php sdk

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

Hi I am newbie in PayPal php sdk and I really need help out how to I fetch multi items product name, quantity & price into PayPal php REST sdk,

I used jQuery for adding multi items to cart, below is my source code
1st this is my code in function.php

```
<div class="product clearfix" style="padding:8px;">
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="product-image">
        <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}"><img src="../resources/{$product_image}" alt="{$row['product_title']}" class="selected"></a>
        <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}"><img src="../resources/{$product_image2}" alt="{$row['product_title']}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desc center">
        <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}">
        <div class="product-title"><h3 style="font-size:15px;">{$row['product_title']}</h3></div>
        </a>
        <a href="include/ajax/add_cart_message.php?id={$row['product_id']}" id="btn1" class="productItem button button-rounded button-reveal button-medium button-border tright" data-lightbox="ajax" data-name="{$row['product_title']}" data-s="{$row['quantity_diff']}" data-price="{$row['product_price']}" data-id="{$row['product_id']}01" data-itemcode="{$row['item_number']}">&#36;{$row['product_price']} <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="variab1">{$row['quantity_diff']}</span></a>
        <a href="include/ajax/add_cart_message.php?id={$row['product_id']}" id="btn2" class="productItem button button-rounded button-reveal button-medium button-border tright" data-lightbox="ajax" data-name="{$row['product_title']}" data-s="{$row['quantity_diff2']}" data-price="{$row['product_price2']}" data-id="{$row['product_id']}02" data-itemcode="{$row['item_number']}">&#36;{$row['product_price2']} <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="variab2">{$row['quantity_diff2']}</span></a>
        <a href="include/ajax/add_cart_message.php?id={$row['product_id']}" id="btn3" class="productItem button button-rounded button-reveal button-medium button-border tright" data-lightbox="ajax" data-name="{$row['product_title']}" data-s="{$row['quantity_diff3']}" data-price="{$row['product_price3']}" data-id="{$row['product_id']}03" data-itemcode="{$row['item_number']}">&#36;{$row['product_price3']} <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="variab3">{$row['quantity_diff3']}</span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

each button clicked will send data to jQuery collect it and output to modal html like below

```
<!-- modals -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Shopping Cart</h4></div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:0px;">
                <form action="order_process.php" method="post">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead style="background:#1ABC9C; color:white;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Image</th>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right;">Subtotal</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="output">

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Checkout with PayPal"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Continue Shopping</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and below is the jQuery script output the data to #output

```
</script>
    <script>
        var shopcart =[];
        jQuery(document).ready( function($){
            outputCart();

            $('#output').on('click','.remove-item',function(){
                var itemToDelete = $('.remove-item').index(this);
                shopcart.splice(itemToDelete,1);
                sessionStorage['sca'] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
                outputCart();
            })

            $('.productItem').click(function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var imgpath = $(this).closest('.product').find('img' + '.selected').attr('src');
                if (!imgpath) {
                    imgpath = 'default.jpg';
                }
                console.log(imgpath);
                var iteminfo = $(this.dataset)[0];
                iteminfo.qty = 1;
                var itemincart = false;
                $.each(shopcart, function (index, value) {
                    ///console.log(index + ' ' + value.id);
                    if(value.id == iteminfo.id) {
                        iteminfo.imgpath = imgpath;
                        value.qty = parseInt(value.qty) + parseInt(iteminfo.qty);
                        itemincart = true;
                    }
                })
                if(!itemincart){
                    iteminfo.imgpath = imgpath;
                    shopcart.push(iteminfo);
                }
                console.log(shopcart);
                sessionStorage["sca"] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
                outputCart();
                ///
            })


            function outputCart() {
                if (sessionStorage["sca"] != null) {
                    shopcart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["sca"].toString());
                    $('#checkoutdiv').show();
                }
                var holderHTML = '';
                var total = 0;
                var itemCnt = 0;
                $.each(shopcart, function (index, value) {
                    var stotal = value.qty * value.price;   
                    total += stotal;
                    itemCnt += parseInt(value.qty);
                    holderHTML += '<tr><td><a href=product.php?id=' + formatId(value.id) + '><img src="' + value.imgpath + '" width="100px"></a></td><td><input type="hidden" name="item_name_' + a + '" value="' + value.name + ' ' + value.s + '"><a href=product.php?id=' + formatId(value.id) + '>' + value.name + '(' + value.s + ')<br>#' + value.itemcode + '</a></td><td class="center"><input type="hidden" name="amount_' + a + '" value="' + formatMoney(value.price) + '"> ' + formatMoney(value.price) + ' </td><td><input size="5" type="number" class="dynquantity" name="quantity_' + a + '" value="' + value.qty + '" data-id="' + value.id + '"></td><td class="center"> ' + formatMoney(stotal) + '</td><td class="center"><span class="btn btn-danger remove-item">x</span></td></tr>'; 

                })

                holderHTML += '<tr><td colspan="4" style="text-align:right;">Total: </td><td style="text-align:right;">' + formatMoney(total) +'</td><td>';
                $('#output').html(holderHTML);
                $('.total').html(formatMoney(total));
                $('.items').html(itemCnt);

            }
            function formatMoney(m){
                return '$' + (m);
            }
            function formatId(n){
                return (n / 100).toFixed(0);
            }
        })
    </script>
```

in order_process.php, how do I fetch those datas to PayPal php sdk? I try my best and it's not working at all, please help

```
<?php 

use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

require 'app/startpp.php';

if (!isset($_POST['item_name_[]'], $_POST['amount_[]'], $_POST['quantity_[]'])) {

}

$product = $_POST['item_name_[]'];
$price = $_POST['amount_[]'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity_[]'];

$total = $price * $quantity;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item3 = new Item();
$item3->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item4 = new Item();
$item4->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item5 = new Item();
$item5->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item6 = new Item();
$item6->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$item7 = new Item();
$item7->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setQuantity($quantity)
    ->setPrice($price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $item5, $item6, $item7]);


$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('CAD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetail($detail);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItmeList($itemList)
    ->setDescription('PayForSomething Payment')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=true')
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=false');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

try {
    $payment->create($paypal);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

echo $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, you have a typo in your code:

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItmeList($itemList)
    ->setDescription('PayForSomething Payment')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
```

Change `setItmeList` to `setItemList`.

After fixing this, on the client side, you add `[]` to your field names, for example: `item_name[]`. On the server side, you can then read all the item names with `$item_names = $_POST['item_name']`. You don't need the brackets in the identifier on the server side - you have written `$_POST['item_name_[]']`, but that is wrong. Then, verify that you have received the arrays - then proceed with your Paypal code.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but my browser still show Notice: Undefined index: item_name[] , amount[], etc....

Comment: Please edit your question and add all your error messages. Without them, it is very hard to see what is wrong because you need to dig through all your code, while the error message makes it quite clear. I have expanded my answer.